# is it possible to use same database for 2 different sites

Tags: magento-1.9, database, multidomain

we have a magento site. we are planning to make this site as marketplace so sellers can sell their products in our site

as like http://www.amazon.in/

in the above site , they are using below sub domain for sellers to register and upload their products

https://sellercentral.amazon.in

can we do something like this using magento, if so is we have to create 2 sites as

abc.com and seller.abc.com and use the same database for both ?

please guide me about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how to create multiple website check [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/) also

In admin panel, go to System->Configuration and click on “Manage Stores”
Click on “Main Website” to change it’s name to “Website 1″ or however you want to call it. (I’ll call mine “Website 1″ for the purposes of this article).
In “code” field there, write something like “website_1″.

Do same for “Main Website Store”. Call it “Website store 1″.

And guess what… do same for “Default Store View” that you can find on same interface.
How to call it?
Hm… I’ll call mine “English Store View”

I’ll write “english_store_view_website_1″ in “code” field there.

Ok, let’s go make second one…
Add website named “Website 2″ with code “website_2″.
Add store called “Website store 2″ and assign it to Website 2 that you can chose from dropdown.
Add new store view called “English Store View” with code “english_store_view_website_2″ and
assign it to “Website 2″ that you can find in dropdown.

By now you should have 2 websites with 1 language each.

Add two more store views.

```
Call first “German Store View” with code “german_store_view_website_1″.
Call second “German Store View” with code “german_store_view_website_2″.
```

Assign them to corresponding websites.

Let’s see what we have at this moment:

```
1) a) Website 1 (code: website_1) – Website Store 1 – English Store View (code: english_store_view_website_1)
b) Website 1 (code: website_1) – Website Store 1 – German Store View (code: german_store_view_website_1)

2) a) Website 2 (code: website_2) – Website Store 2 – English Store View (code: english_store_view_website_2)
b) Website 2 (code: website_2) – Website Store 2 – German Store View (code: german_store_view_website_2)
```

Of course, I didn’t mentioned that you will need to chose root category for your stores, do what ever you like there.

Ok, let’s say we want url to be handled this way:

```
1) http://www.yourdomain.com/website_1
2) http://www.yourdomain.com/website_2
```

In your Magento installation directory, make 2 directories called “website_1″ and “website_2″
Copy .htacces and index.php from your root directory in each of those new directories.

In .htaccess search for `“RewriteBase /”` line and replace it with `“RewriteBase /website_1/”` in first directory, and
search for `“RewriteBase /”` line and replace it with `“RewriteBase /website_2/”` in second directory.

In both directories open `index.php` and change

```
“$compilerConfig = ‘includes/config.php';” to
$compilerConfig = ‘../includes/config.php';

Change $mageFilename = ‘app/Mage.php'; to $mageFilename = ‘../app/Mage.php';
```

In same file make sure to edit `Mage::run()` function for each site:

```
Mage::run(‘website_1′, ‘website’);
Mage::run(‘website_2′, ‘website’);
```

Go to System->Configuration and select Current Configuration Scope: Website 1

Set absolute paths to your skin, js and  media directories and set Base URL = http://www.yourdomain.com/website_1  (do that for website_2 too)

Comment: is it possible by using main domain and sub domain instead of multiple store views

Comment: yes you can use that